# How to implement statement which multiplies 1 or 2 or 3 values of the array and checks if the result is in the next array

Tags: java, arrays

My array:

```
int tab[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,40,42,45,48,49,54,56,63,64,63,72,81};
```

i have nine numbers[ids array],i draws max 3 random numbers from an array of ids and one from tab array,  and  i multiply them by yourself and want to check whether the outcome of these numbers are equal to draw number from array.

```
private int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

example.
I draws from an ids array random numbers 3,7,1 and i draw random number from tab array 63
I can not in any way to multiply these numbers to result 63.I want draw from tab array 3 7 1 21 so i can gain the good result.

CAn u help me ?

```
private int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
private static final int  a=7;
    private static final int  b=7;
    Button buttons [][]= new Button[a][b];

int tablica[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,40,42,45,48,49,54,56,63,64,63,72,81};
        int i = tablica[rand.nextInt(36)];

for ( int qq = 1; qq < a; qq++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

            won.addView(tableRow);


        for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {
            myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setTypeface(type);

            final int number = new Random().nextInt(9);      
            final int rand = (ids[number]);

            myButton.setText(""+rand);

            myButton.setId(rand);
            myButton.setTag(rand);

            buttons[q][qq]=myButton;

  }
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                                int buttonValue = (int)v.getTag();

                     total *= buttonValue;
                     score.setText(String.valueOf(total));
});
    }
}
```

I have 9x9 buttons tabble and multiply numbers from them.

[image]

so i click buttons to gain 15. but i cant gain it.. becase there is no 3 and 5. how to check if there is 3 and 5 button if not draw another result which i can gain pushing this numbers in button.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and what the error/problem was that you saw.

Comment: If you know what your result is, then use prime factorization to figure out what numbers you need to equal your result.

Comment: It isn't likely that you will get 3 random ids to equal the random number you select from tabs. Do you want to be able to select a tab and then find the values that can be multiplied to get the tab you select? If so that is recursion or math logic

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do. So you're trying to draw three random numbers and then check if, if they're multiplied, their product is your 'target' number? Is that correct?

Comment: please check edit. i didnt paste all the code because is extensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two booleans: 
(example)
num1
num2 
Make 2 ints
Hold1 = 0;
Hold2 = 0;

put this in your for loop.

Try:

```
if(i%rand == 0 && rand != hold1)
{
   num1 = true;
   hold1 = rand;
}

if(i%rand == 0 && num1 && rand*hold1 == i)
{
   num2 = true;
}
```

then make another if statement:

```
if(num1 && num2)
{
  (rest of program)
}

else{(for loop again}
```

Comment: Is that what you're trying to go for?

Comment: Your problem makes more sense now, hopefully my answer does.

Comment: I made a couple more edits, the first if checks for:                     A) If the number is divisible by the first num on the calc pad.     B) If the number is not repeated.                                    The second:                                                           A) button is divisible b) 1st num is already found and c) the first num is multiplied by second to make total. The other loop resets it if there are no numbers

Comment: Just add a third if to make it for 3 numbers

Comment: Need any help with that?

Comment: I'd have to read and understand that in a moment. Also, don't leave threads open if they haven't been answered, you should mark this complete, then we can continue on

Comment: so should accept just answer to make it completed ?

Comment: Yep. As for your code, I'll take a look at it soon. Meant to say if they *have* been accepted.

Comment: maybe i have solution to do this... get all values from buttons and make array from them with results using max 3 numbers ?

Comment: You could, but you need a way to check for solutions, which my if statements could help with.